# THTTPRio SOAP TByteDynArray return value, No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

Tags: delphi, encoding, output, soap-client, binary-data

I have a unit that was created with WSDL importer from Delphi 10.2 and want to consume a webservice that, sometimes, returns a file in a TByteDynArray.

When I invoke the webservice:

```
ReturnedData := GetGestaoFicheiroWS.consultarFicheiroIdFile(FileID);
```

I'm getting this error:

No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

and this error is raized in System function TEncoding.GetString, line 32829:

```
raise EEncodingError.CreateRes(@SNoMappingForUnicodeCharacter);
```

This should return a file that should be loaded into a TByteDynArray variable of ReturnedData.

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve this?

Comment: It means that somewhere in the process the bytes are being converted to string leading to this error. You will have to do some debugging.

Comment: Well, I did actualy. Sometimes the response only returns string data, but sometimes it will return a file as a TbyteDynArray. The structure of the response variable is like   ficheiroWSModel = class(TRemotable)
  private
    Fmensagem: string;
    ...
    FlstErrosAlertasZip: TByteDynArray;
Sometimes FlstErrosAlertasZip comes empty and sometimes will return a file and it is here where I get the error.

Comment: @CarlosMatos please include the response code into the question. Comments are not for that...